# Android: how to align 2 images on a splash screen

Tags: android, image, bitmap, splash-screen, android-gravity

I would like to use a splah screen containing 2 images:

- the main image must be fully center
- the secondary image must be center between the bottom and the main image

The expected render is something like this:
[image: expected splash]

But I don't see how to get this, and my second image is bottom aligned:
[image: actual splash]

The XML of my splash is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/ComplementColor" />
                <padding 
                    android:left="0dip" 
                    android:top="0dip"
                    android:right="0dip" 
                    android:bottom="0dip" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/main_logo"
               android:gravity="center" />
        </item>
        <item>
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/secondary_logo"
               android:gravity="bottom" />
        </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've finally choose another solution close to that  suggested by @Leonardo Cavazzani.

I've added a margin to the bottom image like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/ComplementColor" />
          <padding 
            android:left="0dip" 
            android:top="0dip"
            android:right="0dip" 
            android:bottom="0dip" />
      </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/main_logo"
              android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
    <item
      android:bottom="40dp">
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/secondary_logo"
              android:gravity="bottom" />
     </item>
  </layer-list>
```

Comment: but its not a good solution as it gives issue with different device resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

Set a marginBottom for your bitmap

```
<bitmap android:src="@drawable/secondary_logo"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="100dp" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this doesn't work.
In the XML editor, I get the warning "attribute is not declared", and when I launch the app, it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it trough the LayoutXML instead of the Drawable.XML

A simple LayoutManager where the first image is centered and the second alignedToTheBottom of the first plus topMargin solve your problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about...
Do I need to replace `layer-list` by `LinearLayout`?
Or do you have a sample?

Comment: Yes, thats what i meant