# Android: how to align 2 images one in center and one in bottom

Tags: android

How to align two images one in center and one in bottom using LinearLayout
because as i found RelativeLayout marked as legacy
[image: example]
Here question but for splash screen
[Android: how to align 2 images on a splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46245887/android-how-to-align-2-images-on-a-splash-screen)

Comment: any update for this question ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/image_1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image_2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to align two images one in center and one in bottom using
>   LinearLayout

For `LinearLayout`, you can set the [orientation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) to vertical

To make the image center, use  `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`

**Code**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/image"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/image2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="89dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/child_big" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Play with marginBottom and marginTop attributes!