# How to create Android splash screen with images and percent position

Tags: android, android-drawable, splash-screen

I am trying to create an Android splash screen that has two images: one in the center of the screen and one that is about 20% away from the bottom of the screen. Is there any way to do this?

The approach I tried thus far is to have a SplashActivity as the first activity and the manifest file sets the theme as SplashTheme:

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then in styles.xml I define this theme:

```
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    </style>
```

Next I create the drawable file background_splash.xml and this is where I have questions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/dark_gray" />
        <padding
            android:left="0dip"
            android:top="0dip"
            android:right="0dip"
            android:bottom="0dip" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/mainlogo"/>

</item>

<item android:bottom="@dimen/splash_bottom">
    <bitmap android:src="@mipmap/bottom_logo"
        android:gravity="bottom" />
</item>

</layer-list>
```

This actually sort-of works, the mainlogo is indeed in the center and the bottom_logo is some distance above the bottom. The problem is that I need to specify values in dp for splash_bottom in dimens.xml. Doing this accurately for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi xhdpi etc is really hard to get right.

Isn't there a way inside the drawable file background_splash.xml to place the bottom_logo 20% from the bottom of the screen?

The desired splash screen looks something like this (not the actual screen - I borrowed this from another SO post - see [Android: how to align 2 images on a splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46245887/android-how-to-align-2-images-on-a-splash-screen)):

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you can add some hand-drawn image or mockup of your expected output.

Comment: see updated post. I added someone else's splash screen that shows the general idea. The SO post I borrowed it from has the answer I started with, but used a hardcoded dp bottom margin. My margin was specified in dimens.xml so it has more flexibility, but it is still hard to get right for the wide range of Android devices available. Would love to see a better solution.

Comment: you can create 2 seperate drawable and drop them in the layout, will that work for you?

Comment: is there any animation in your Splash screen or simply a Screen with Two images like you post?

Comment: you should create a dimension folder for every dimension. That's is fashion of modern app developer and method of recommended high developers.

Answer (score 1):

**"layer-list & item" have no percentage properties to set their position.**

**To implement your idea, you should use layout XML file**.

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In SplashActivity.java

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // SET no title , full-screen mode
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // SET activity_splash.xml as layout
        final View viewSplash = View.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_splash, null);
        setContentView(viewSplash);

        // Gradient Animation
        AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.5f, 1.0f); // change alpha from 0.5 to 1.0
        anim.setDuration(5000); // animate in 5000ms
        viewSplash.setAnimation(anim);
        anim.setAnimationListener(
                new Animation.AnimationListener(){
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                        // redirect to the other screen, such as MainActivity
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);

                                        // close SplashActivity
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                });
    }
}
```

activity_splash.xml might be one of followings;

**1. *layout_weight* of LinearLayout**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/dark_gray">

<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@mipmap/mainlogo"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:src="@mipmap/bottom_logo"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: used layout_weight of LinearLayout]
Screenshot.1

**2. *layout_constraintGuide_percent* of Guidline**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_gray">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/mainlogo"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/bottom_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".8"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/bottom_logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: used layout_constraintGuide_percent of Guidline] Screenshot.2

**3. *layout_marginLeftPercent* of PercentRelativeLayout**

*But this class was deprecated in API level 26.1.0. so i did not upload the xml about that.*

Comment: is it available for every dimension?

Comment: @WhitehorseJJ  of coz., recommend you run it once,

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `@dimen/splash_bottom` in `background_splash.xml` file.

Now, the position of bottom image is changed according to dimension value.
To fix the issue, you should do as following methods.
I believe anything in the `res/` folder can use "Configuration Qualifiers". So for example, you can have a `values-xxhdpi`, `values-sw600dp-mdpi-land/`, `values-w400dp` folder, and so on.

Other words, you have to create ***different values folder for different screens***.

```
values-sw720dp          10.1” tablet 1280x800 mdpi

values-sw600dp          7.0”  tablet 1024x600 mdpi

values-sw480dp          5.4”  480x854 mdpi 
values-sw480dp          5.1”  480x800 mdpi 

values-xxhdpi           5.5"  1080x1920 xxhdpi
values-xxxhdpi           5.5" 1440x2560 xxxhdpi

values-xhdpi            4.7”   1280x720 xhdpi 
values-xhdpi            4.65”  720x1280 xhdpi 

values-hdpi             4.0” 480x800 hdpi
values-hdpi             3.7” 480x854 hdpi

values-mdpi             3.2” 320x480 mdpi

values-ldpi             3.4” 240x432 ldpi
values-ldpi             3.3” 240x400 ldpi
values-ldpi             2.7” 240x320 ldpi
```

Thanks.